# How to play local file in macOs objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio

I'm creating a music player, and i already have relative path of songs which is "/Users/username/Music/song.mp3" and my code is this

```
    NSURL * localURL = [NSURL URLWithString:audioPath];

      AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:localURL];
      self.audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem : playerItem];
      self.isPlaying = @"false";

    [self.audioPlayer play];
```

But my macOs app is not playing anything, and my song.mp3 is playable with iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURL * localURL = [NSURL URLWithString:audioPath];
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
NSURL * localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Refer to my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779683/mpmovieplayercontroller-doesnt-play-from-documents-folder/22661656#22661656)